# How to set group_concat_max_len in codeigniter active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, group-concat

I have tried to set `group_concat_max_len` in codeigniter with `$this->db->query('SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000')` but it doesn't work.

I have tried like:

```
$q = 'SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000';
$this->db->query($q);

$this->db->select("group_concat(id) ids");
$this->db->from("table_name");
$data = $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

but this does not give all data. any idea about this.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found solution by using `SET SESSION` instead of `SET GLOBAL`.

Code is like :

```
$this->db->simple_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=15000');

$this->db->select("group_concat(id) ids");
$this->db->from("table_name");
$data = $this->db->get()->row_array();
```